# How can I easily lock-down access to an Azure resource?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-aks

I have a resource (specifically, a Kubernetes service deployed to my AKS cluster) to which I want to limit access. I've looked around through the MSDN documentation on [What is Azure Virtual Network?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-overview), [VPN Gateway design](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/design), and more, but I don't see a clear way that I can either:

- Require AAD authentication before a specific IP/Port is accessed, or
- Whitelist access coming *from* a specific IP/subnet (eg, specifying CIDR format `www.xxx.yyy.zzz/nn` that should get access).

There seem to be ways to restrict access that require I install some a RADIUS VPN client, but I don't want to require this. It seems like there are a ton of hoops to jump through -- is there a way I can block all incoming traffic to my AKS cluster *except* from specific AAD roles or from specific IP ranges?

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to understand what you intend to use AKS for (web site, batch computing, etc.)

First you should fully explore the networking options offered by the service itself.  Start with locking down to your personal IP address and the service will likely (based on Azure docs) append a deny-all to the end of your networking rules.  To get the IP address it sees you from, try [IP Chicken](https://www.ipchicken.com/).

I offer two additional options:  Application Gateway or API Management.

One way to lock this down, based on the information you shared, is Application Gateway.

[Application Gateway (Product Page)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-gateway/)

> Ingress Controller for AKS
>
> "Application Gateway Ingress Controller (AGIC) allows you to use Application Gateway as the ingress for an Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster." - from [Azure Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/features#ingress-controller-for-aks)

[API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-key-concepts)

You also have API Management paired with policies on that resource.  It can restrict by AAD (check pricing tier for details) and IP address (on any pricing tier).

If the organic networking options of AKS don't cover your use case, I would choose API Management.  Price and options are better for what it seems you are aiming for.

Comment: I have multiple components in my AKS cluster, but it's a web server that I need to (partially) expose. When you say "start with locking down to your personal IP address" - I don't see any options to do this within my AKS resource.

I tried creating a new AKS cluster with a VNet, then an API Management resource. I assume I would configure my API Management to use my AKS' VNet, but when I do so, it "[Fails] to scale API Management service."

Somewhat tangentially, the pricing for API Management seems pretty extreme if all I'm looking for is to be able to restrict access.